# Gparted showing whole DIsk unallocated

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, fdisk, testdisk

I have a laptop dual booted with Windows and Linux. I was using gparted to resize a partition(say F) in my disk. But I had to cancel it. Then I booted to windows and there it was showing my F partition to be raw and showing that I should format it. By googling I found a software testDisk to recover my partition. As I remember I followed the steps given in [tutorial](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) properly. It asked to reboot to write down the changes. When I rebooted there was some grub terminal with some commands written. I entered exit command and then I took me to some other(new grub type) window where I have option to reboot to windows. When I did so, it said some type of errors in disk and you need to use recovery tools, and there were option for trying again, and for UEFI firmware settings. I just exited it and then shutdown the pc.

Then I again rebooted with live cd which I am currenly using to write this. I opened gparted there It is showing me the whole disk is unallocated. I used the commands fdisk -l -u,and it's output is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EBA95511-431A-42DD-8D9E-7B13AAF4AC3B

Device     Start    End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 534527  532480  260M EFI System




Disk /dev/sdb: 7.6 GiB, 8178892800 bytes, 15974400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0121a2aa

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 15974399 15972352  7.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1926041600 bytes, 3761800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Is there any way I can recover my Disk now?

Comment: Do you remember what testdisk did? It sounds like it went relatively well, since you could boot into windows afterwards, but then windows decided to somehow erase the partitions... or maybe the disk is failing? You could try testdisk again from a live ISO (usb/dvd/etc)...?

Answer (score 1):

I'd give TestDisk another try; but before doing so, read the documentation more thoroughly, and maybe find an online tutorial or two. (I don't have any specific recommendations.) At this point, the disk is completely unpartitioned, except for the EFI System Partition (ESP), so there's very little to be lost by trying TestDisk again, if your alternative is to re-install everything from scratch. TestDisk *can* usually recover partitions, so there's a good chance you'll get something back.

That said, aborting a partition resize operation midway is almost never a good thing to do, and whatever partition was being adjusted may be badly damaged. TestDisk might or might not recover it, and even if TestDisk does recover it, it may have filesystem damage -- perhaps enough that you'll have to abandon it and recover files from a backup (or, worse, rely on [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or something similar; these tools can be hit-or-miss and are likely to leave a huge pile of files through which you must sift). Despite the possibility of such damage, there's also a significant possibility that you'll recover at least some partitions and data.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I mistakenly deleted the whole disk except the EFI partition. So I have to install windows scratch from recovery. I think I should close this question.